# MathML in HTML5: changing math font

Tags: html, user-interface, mathml

Let's say I have an HTML5 document with some MathML in it. I set the font of the body of the page but it doesn't change the font used for MathML characters:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Example of MathML embedded in an HTML5 file</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: courier;">
    Quadratic formula
    <math><mrow>
      <mi>x</mi>
      <mo>=</mo>
      <mfrac>
        <mrow>
          <mo form="prefix">−</mo>
          <mi>b</mi>
          <mo>&PlusMinus;</mo>
          <msqrt>
            <msup>
              <mi>b</mi>
              <mn>2</mn>
            </msup>
            <mo>−</mo>
            <mn>4</mn>
            <mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo>
            <mi>a</mi>
            <mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo>
            <mi>c</mi>
          </msqrt>
        </mrow>
        <mrow>
          <mn>2</mn>
          <mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo>
          <mi>a</mi>
        </mrow>
      </mfrac>
    </mrow></math>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will display the text "Quadratic formula" in courier but the MathML stays in the default page font. How can I change the font used for MathML?

Comment: `math { font-family: courier; }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably read [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_MathML_Project/Fonts) on the Mozilla Developer Network. I'm guessing the following paragraph is applicable in your case:

> Mathematical formulas make use of various symbols represented by
>   specific Unicode characters. Mozilla can display any of these symbols
>   provided suitable Unicode fonts are installed. Furthermore, in
>   accordance with the W3C CSS2 recommendation on fonts, authors can
>   specify an ordered list of particular fonts which they prefer (using
>   the font-family property of CSS), with the assurance that Mozilla's
>   font engine will hunt for alternate fonts whenever their specified
>   fonts are not found on a particular user's system.

One of the Mozilla `MathML` developers seems to blog quite regularly. There are two recent posts which will be of interest to you:

1. [Installation of mathematical fonts](http://www.maths-informatique-jeux.com/blog/frederic/?post/2012/06/23/Mozilla-MathML-Project%3a-installation-of-mathematical-fonts)
2. [About mathematical fonts](http://www.maths-informatique-jeux.com/blog/frederic/?post/2012/04/21/Mozilla-MathML-Project%3a-about-mathematical-fonts)

The upshot seems to be that, in order to guarantee decent rendering of `MathML`, you need your users to install either [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), [STIX](http://www.stixfonts.org/) or [Asana Math](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Asana_Math_fonts) fonts.

Answer (score 1):

it renders courier in jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/8VKJg/  what browser/operating system are you using?

Including MathJax.js in the fiddle renders this correctly:

```
<script src="//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"
async>

</script>
```

[jsfiddle with MathJax.js rendering correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/8VKJg/26/)

Comment: No thanks ;) Great to see real complex mathematical expressions in the browser(s), lovely. Studied econometrics myself and did loads of math ;)

Comment: i share your enthusiasm, although i'll defer to your knowledge of math, as mine is greatly lacking ;)

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).